Replacing 3 way switch knocked out my entire circuit
I was recently swapping out an old toggle 3 way switch to a paddle switch. I noticed there were 2 black wires going to the common, then an additional white a black traveler. I hooked the new switch up exactly like the old and I keep tripping the breaker. Any help on this would be great. To sum it up I have 3 black wires (only 1 is live) and one white wire

Pictures of the switch and how you have things connected would help.  And if you took pictures of things before you disconnected the old switch, that would be tremendously helpful as well.

I assuming you replaced an old three way with a new three way switch.  If the wires were reconnected the exact same way(?), then the problem should be with a hot touching a ground wire or the box(metal).

Yes replaced the exact same way! I had it pulled it out from the wall when I tried turning the breaker back on so nothing was touching

Each brand/type of 3-way switch is different. Make sure you really know which wires are travelers vs. common and then look at the new switch instructions to figure it out - e.g., it could be travelers were top left/right and are not right top/bottom, etc.

I keep tripping the breaker. Means I hooked the new switch up exactly like the old is a false belief, unless the breaker was tripping before you changed the switch. Get over it and start figuring out where things went wrong. Different terminals, didn't keep track of the 3 black wires correctly, etc.

Why did you replace the old switch? was it faulty, or just ugly?

I can't see any way to miss-wire a 3 way switch that would cause breaker trips, the sole exception would be connecting the supply to the ground, or ground to one of the terminals.

Disconnect wires until the problem goes away.  The last wire disconnected will be the one that leads to the problem. so follow that wire.
Start with the wires furthest from the supply. So the two travelers in any order then the branch wire and finally the supply (live) wire.
